# Registrar decimales en un jsp mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Quisiera registrar un dato que esta en decimal(15,2) que esta en mysql en un jsp el cual no me deja registrar.
Este mismo dato si lo puedo modificar en otro jsp pero registrar como nuevo no puedo.

este es el codigo que tengo en registrar:

## Registro de Clientes

```
    <%
        if(request.getParameter("nomcliente")!=null&&request.getParameter("ruccliente")!=null&&request.getParameter("stcliente")!=null&&request.getParameter("dircliente")!=null&&request.getParameter("ciucliente")!=null&&request.getParameter("cecliente")!=null&&request.getParameter("tlcliente")!=null&&Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("lcscliente"))!=0.0){

                Clientes cl= new Clientes(0,request.getParameter("nomcliente"),request.getParameter("ruccliente"),request.getParameter("stcliente"),request.getParameter("dircliente"),request.getParameter("ciucliente"),request.getParameter("cecliente"),request.getParameter("tlcliente"),Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("lcscliente")));

           boolean respuesta=Consulta.insertarCliente(cl);

           if (respuesta!=false)
               out.println("Datos ingresados "+respuesta );
           else
               out.println("Datos ingresados "+respuesta );
        }
    %>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @darefone. Por favor brinda más información respecto a tu problema. Agrega qué has intentado, qué código tienes y por qué es que no te deja "registrar": ¿insertar desde la aplicación Web a tu base de datos MySQL, leer el dato de la base de datos y mostrarlo en tu aplicación, qué exactamente? Recuerda que lo único que podemos conocer de tu problema es lo que nos expliques en el texto de la pregunta.

Comment: No queda muy claro lo que necesitas, intenta editar la pregunta y explica mejor tu problema, en caso de que los haya incluide los logs de los errores

Comment: Veo que has editado la pregunta. Ahora, agrega más información al respecto: qué error sale, cuál es el stacktrace donde se describe el error, cuál es el código de `Consulta#insertarCliente`.

Answer (score 0):

Java no tiene el tipo Decimal nativo por lo que necesitarás utilizar BigDecimal que es una clase con objetos inmutables.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: al momento que lo ingreso en el jsp lo estoy jalando con Double y si modifica el dato pero no puedo registrarlo

Comment: No me fiaría mucho de esta sentencia Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("lcscliente"))!=0.0 ya que Double no tiene precisión preferiría lo cambiaras a BigDecimal ese si tiene precisión.

Comment: Si no te sale ningun error en el constructor entonces si estas almacenando bien el Double, por lo que el problema va a ser en Consulta al hacer el insertarCliente(cl).

Te recomiendo también no hagas if con tantas sentencias al mismo tiempo, son difíciles de debugear, te recomiendo hagas algo así
boolean contieneDatos = contieneDatos && nueva sentencia; 
repitiendo lo anterior tantas veces como sea necesario.

No es lo mejor pero hará tu código más entendible te recomiendo el libro del Tio Bob Código Limpio  Robert C. Martin

Comment: Disculpa mi estimado Ivan hay forma de que puedas apoyar vía remota